# Does protobuf give size and speed gain in comparison to HTTP/2?

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, http2

HTTP/2 is binary, as well as protobuf.

If I use HTTP/2 on my server, then do I still need to use protobuf if I use it to reduce size of messages or will be JSON gzipped and sent via HTTP/2 comparatively the same?

JSON seems to be more human readable and easier to debug as well as doesn't need an additional client library.

Answer (score 5):

These are orthogonal. HTTP/2 is a binary framing/multiplexing protocol on top of sockets. It can handle multiple parallel requests/responses on a single TCP stream, where HTTP/1 can not. From an application point of view however both provide a binary stream in request and response direction, into which you can put either text or JSON or protobuf encoded data or anything else you desire.

If using protobuf on application level is more optimal (because of space savings, faster encoding decoding, etc.) it will be more optimal on both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. If using JSON is good enough for the application then it's the right choice for HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

HTTP/2 may be faster as an underlying transport for delivering the binary request and response data compared to HTTP/1.1 or for initiating the request at all, but that depends on the data and usage scenario.

Comment: Also note that http://grpc.io -- Google's RPC system -- is based on Protocol Buffers and HTTP/2, demonstrating that they go great together.

Comment: That's true. However gRPC is even a little bit special as it uses some features that are not even exposed by many HTTP/1.1 libraries, e.g. sending and receiving trailing headers. It thereby has some tighter requirements on the underlying HTTP implementation than most other HTTP based systems.